# replace UTF8 characters in String

Tags: android, utf-8, replace

I have a simple string with Chinese characters in my Android application and want to replace one character with another...

As a sample, I have this code:

```
String old_string = "啤酒";
String new_string = old_string.replaceAll("一", "啤");
Log.d(TAG, "transformed "+old_string+" into "+new_string);
```

This will not do anything:

```
transformed 啤酒 into 啤酒
```

Also tried with `replace` instead of `replaceAll` without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try swapping the values around:

```
String new_string = old_string.replaceAll("啤", "一");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to switch the order of parameters in replaceAll call :

```
replaceAll("啤", "--")
```